# Bar plot mean from two or more files in R

Tags: r

I have two text files, A.txt and B.txt (perhaps more in the future). Each text file looks like this (but with different values):

```
1
2
5
6
7
```

I would like to plot the average of each row in the text files, for example, combine the text files into a matrix that looks something like this:

```
1 5
2 7
5 5
6 9
7 7
```

And then make a bar plot of 5 bars, each representing the average for each row (1+5/2, 2+7/2, etc.). I would also like to plot error bars representing the standard error for each bar graph (assuming I have more than one text file).

I'm able to do the following for a single text file:

```
my.data <- read.table('A.txt')
barplot(t(my.data))
```

Which will graph one text file. But not sure how to take the two text files, combine them, graph the mean, and produce error bars. Any suggestions or links to resources?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
my.data <- do.call("cbind", lapply(list.files(pattern="*.txt"), read.table))
my.data <- rowMeans(my.data)
barplot(t(my.data))
```

Note, this untested.

Comment: Untested, but works... (+1). To add the error bars, perhaps the OP should not overwrite the original data in the second line, so they can perform the necessary calculations to create the bars.

Comment: Didn't see the extra comment; so I can just do rowMeans and save it in another variable. Then do some kind of rowStd(my.data)/sqrt(length(data)) in R speak of course?